# PostgreSQL Error while describe or any operation on imported data

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.4

I have imported a SQL dump into a database named Test and now when I try to describe the table it give me an error as the relation does not exits. But when I do the same operation on information_schema.columns I get the results. Also modification or select operation is getting failed with same error.

```
# \connect Test
Password for user postgres:

psql (8.4.18)
You are now connected to database "Test".

Test=# \d
                          List of relations
         Schema |         Name          |   Type   |  Owner
        --------+-----------------------+----------+----------
        . . .
        public | TESTEMP               | table    | postgres
        . . .

        Test-# \d+ TestEmp;
        Did not find any relation named "Test".

    Test=# select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'TestEmp';
        column_name
    --------------------
     lastname
     firstname

    Test=# alter table TestEmp Add column "PerEmp"  BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    ERROR:  relation "testemp" does not exist

Test=# select * from TestEmp;
ERROR:  relation "testemp" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from testemp;
                      ^
MediaService=#
```

Any thoughts why these errors are being reported.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Seems the tables are created using quoted strings due to which it become case sensitive. So one I did below it describe the tables without any errors.

```
#\d+ "TESTEMP"
                    Table "public.TESTEMP"
       Column       |            Type             | Modifiers
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
. . .
```

Just keeping this question for future.